# WordPress Custom Short Code help

Tags: php, wordpress, short

Anyone familiar with WordPress shortcodes?  I could really use a hand!  I've inserted the following code into my functions.php file for the theme I'm using...

```
function create_slideshow_header($atts, $content = null){
    return '<div class="item_heading">'.$content.'</div>';
}
add_shortcode('slideshow_heading', 'create_slideshow_header');
function create_slideshow_white_header($atts, $content = null){
    return '<span id="dyn">'.$content.'</span>';
}
add_shortcode('slideshow_heading_white', 'create_slideshow_white_header');
function create_slideshow_content($atts, $content = null){
    return '<div class="item_content">'.$content.'</div>';
}
add_shortcode('slideshow_content', 'create_slideshow_content');
```

Now, I was led to believe by several tutorials that this should allow me to insert the following into the text editor in the WP backend...

[slideshow_heading]SLIDESHOW HEADER[/slideshow_heading]

...and the SLIDESHOW HEADER text would be wrapped in the appropriate HTML.... but it's just displaying the above as regular text.  I've cleared my cache, etc...

Is there something I'm doing wrong?  Thanks in advance!

**SOLUTION**

I failed to mention that I was using the page.ly MultiEdit plugin--which uses "custom fields" to create extra editable regions.  WordPress conveniently doesn't parse shortcodes in custom fields.  Normally, you can create a filter for each custom field, but since this is a plugin, you can just edit the multiedit.php file, and change line 63 from

```
echo $GLOBALS['multiEditDisplay'][$index][0];
```

to

```
echo apply_filters('the_content',$GLOBALS['multiEditDisplay'][$index][0]);
```

With a little work, you can turn Wordpress into a truly amazing CMS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually checked out your code, it works for me. Your usage is right.

Try adding a die() in there to see whether the method is called in your case.

Comment: Which WordPress theme are you using?

Comment: It's one I coded for a client. On a test environment, Version 3.0. Did the die() work? See if the method is being called at all. Then work from there.

Comment: I should have given you more info!  Thanks for your help -- figured it out.  See my edit!

Comment: Yup just saw it, was wondering how my reply was marked as a correct solution when your problem was still there. Didn't see that coming :D